# Add each line of CSV file into an array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, fopen, fgetcsv

I am almost embarrassed to ask this, but I've been trying to accomplish this task for a few hours now. Without a thorough grasp of the [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) or [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)  functions, I'm a bit lost. Each example I find does not quite work for me.

I'm seeking a way to load each line of a CSV file into one array. For example, if this is my CSV file:

```
Apple,Banana,Orange
Kiwi,Watermelon,Pineapple
Dog,Cat,Bird
```

Then this would be my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Apple,Banana,Orange
    [1] => Kiwi,Watermelon,Pineapple
    [2] => Dog,Cat,Bird
)
```

I'd appreciate any tips. Thanks! :)

---

Just for reference, this is what I have so far:

```
$list = '../reports/apples.csv';

$csvfile = fopen($list,'rb');
while(!feof($csvfile)) {
$listofthings[] = fgetcsv($csvfile);
}
fclose($csvfile);

print_r($listofthings);
```

However, this is producing a multidimensional array as follows, when I'd rather just have one big array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Apple
            [1] => Banana
            [2] => Orange
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Kiwi
            [1] => Watermelon
            [2] => Pineapple
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Dog
            [1] => Cat
            [2] => Bird
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to break the file up by lines, use `file`.

```
$newArray = file('/path/to/file.csv');
```

If you want each comma-delimited value as an element of the array, use `file_get_contents` and explode by a comma.

```
$contents = file_get_contents('/path/to/file.csv');
$newArray = explode(',', $contents);
```

Comment: I noticed the same thing when you first answered and Googled the solution. "\n" worked. Then I came and saw you answered with the same thing! Hah. Marking as solution - this worked for me, and I knew it was going to be something extremely simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could `explode` after reading the file as Nicholas suggests or you could hit it all at once with [`file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php):

```
$lines = file('/path/to/file.csv');
```

Comment: Wish, I could vote up again - I think you've changed my life.

Comment: Hahaha... yeah, the other nice thing is it takes the detect line endings setting into account, so you dont have to worry as much about differing line endings.

Answer (score 0):

are looking for this ??

```
$mytext = "Apple,Banana,Orange
Kiwi,Watermelon,Pineapple
Dog,Cat,Bird";

$line_explode = explode("\n", $mytext);
$comma_explode = array();
foreach ($line_explode as $line) {
  $comma_explode[] = explode(",", $line);
}

print_r($comma_explode);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Apple
            [1] => Banana
            [2] => Orange
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Kiwi
            [1] => Watermelon
            [2] => Pineapple
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Dog
            [1] => Cat
            [2] => Bird
        )

)
```